# curl-like tool for wsgi over unix domain socket

Tags: django, web-applications, curl, wsgi

Is there a command line tool to send requests directly to a wsgi application (django) listening on a unix socket?

An equivalent of:

> curl -X GET http://example.org/index.html

But that would bypass HTTP server and talked directly to the underlying application over wsgi?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for `uwsgi_curl` as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12314245/can-i-use-the-uwsgi-protocol-to-call-http).

Answer (score 0):

The Django application listening on the unix socket uses a different protocol than HTTP, most probably FastCGI. So you cannot use an HTTP client to talk directly with it.

Here you can find an article showing how to use a command line program called cgi-fcgi to talk directly with your application. The article uses Php-fpm, but the concept is the same.

http://www.thatsgeeky.com/2012/02/directly-connecting-to-php-fpm/

Comment: There are possibly certain modes of uWSGI which allow it to listen for HTTP requests over a UNIX socket. I suspect certain over WSGI hosting solutions offer something similar as well. OP needs to state what they are using to host it and setup the scenario where they have it listening to a UNIX socket.

Comment: As far as I know, WSGI applications expect the [WSGI protocol](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3333/), not FastCGI

Answer (score 0):

Django test module has a [Client](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client) that can talk to a wsgi/asgi application.
You can probably use this in a REPL python session for instance.