# Invalid request block size when using SocketIO with Flask and uWSGI

Tags: flask, socket.io, uwsgi, gevent

I'm trying to run a Flask application with SocketIO using uWSGI and gevent.

```
uwsgi --gevent 10 --socket :5000 --module run
```

However, I get the following error:

```
invalid request block size: 21573 (max 4096)...skip
```

This is my code:

```
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()

from flask import Flask, render_template, session, request
from flask.ext.socketio import SocketIO, emit, disconnect

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
application = app

socketio = SocketIO(app)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    session['user'] = '1'
    return render_template('index.html', name='simon')

@socketio.on('my event', namespace='/test')
def test_message(message):
    emit('my response', {'data': message['data']})

@socketio.on('connect', namespace='/test')
def test_connect():
    emit('my response', {'data': 'Connected %s' % session['user']})

@socketio.on('disconnect', namespace='/test')
def test_disconnect():
    print('Client disconnected')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    socketio.run(app)
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are using binary `uwsgi` protocol but accessing your server via `http` protocol. Try replacing `--socket` with `--http-socket`. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/32894820/179581

Comment: That only changes the error message to `invalid HTTP request size (max 4096)...skip`

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that the gevent support in uWSGI does not allow a custom gevent server class to be used, uWSGI provides its own. Unfortunately gevent-socketio needs its own server, which is subclassed from gevent's, so I think it is currently not possible to use uWSGI with Flask-SocketIO or gevent-socketio.

See the [Flask-SocketIO documentation](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#deployment) for alternatives.

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation. So what about use only gevent module instead of Flask-SocketIO in my Flask application and use proxy nginx?

Comment: That could possibly work, but you will need to handle the socket communication yourself, sounds like a lot of work. Much easier to use gunicorn+nginx.