# invalid request block size 21573

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi

I was reading the tutorial provided in 
http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html 
This very tutorial is a great tutorial. I have been able to configure django server on my raspberry pi raspbian system, on my Ubuntu Desktop too.
Now I am trying to do the same on a Virtual Machine, Ubuntu 16.04, nginx server. 
On the line, 
uwsgi --socket :8001 --wsgi-file test.py

I get an error saying 
*invalid request block size 21573* on the terminal
I went through the uwsgi tutorial that said not to use --http for --socket; 
Either way I have not been able to get my webserver running.
 Please help.
Nginx is currently serving a wordpress site on start.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15878176/uwsgi-invalid-request-block-size

Comment: It helped, but why is it that --socket option did not work in Ubuntu Server whereas it worked in raspbian and ubuntu desktop.

Answer (score 4):

With `--socket` option you have to use [uwsgi module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_uwsgi_module.html) in nginx instead of proxy.