# How to really deploy a Django websocket app with nginx?

Tags: python, django, nginx, websocket, uwsgi

For an small Django (1.10.3) app I'd like to have `websockets` and I'm new to the whole `websockets` business. So I searched for a relatively easy to understand project for `django` that enables `websocket` connections and I've found [django-websocket-redis](https://django-websocket-redis.readthedocs.io), which looks easy to use and deploy.

So I created a very [small example](https://github.com/shaoran/django-websocket-mini-example) project (see the github page) where I can test the things I've learnt while reading the documentation of `django-websocket-redis` and I was very quickly able to write something that works.

If I start the app with `./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:3000` and go to http://localhost:3000, then the page is able to make the `websocket` connection, subscribe to a channel and add a `<li>content</li>` on the page whenever a new message from the server arrives. In the `django` app I started a thread that broadcast over the `websocket` interface randomly between 2 and 9 seconds a random string. I was happy with that and I planned to see if the deployment is as easy as it seems.

So I took a closer look at [documentation](https://django-websocket-redis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/running.html) and almost made copy & paste changing only the things that apply to me. I created a file `websockets/wsgi_websocket.py` with

```
import os
import gevent.socket
import redis.connection

redis.connection.socket = gevent.socket

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "websockets.settings")

from ws4redis.uwsgi_runserver import uWSGIWebsocketServer
application = uWSGIWebsocketServer()
```

and a file `websockets/deploy_settings.py` with

```
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', '127.0.0.1', '::1', '192.168.2.117', 'weby.com']

...

INSTALLED_APPS = [ 
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'ws4redis',
    'websockets',
]

....

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'ws4redis.django_runserver.application'

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
os.path.join(os.path.dirname(ws4redis.__file__), "static"),
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "deployment", "static")


WEBSOCKET_URL = '/ws/'
WS4REDIS_EXPIRE = 5
WS4REDIS_PREFIX = 'ws'

SESSION_ENGINE = 'redis_sessions.session'
SESSION_REDIS_PREFIX = 'session'

...
```

In the `index.html` page I do the connection as follows:

```
var ws_url = 'ws://' + window.location.host + '/ws/foobar?subscribe-broadcast&publish-broadcast';
var ws = new WebSocket(ws_url);
...
```

Like I said, in `DEBUG = True` mode everything works fine. I installed  `nginx` (I use Gentoo Linux, so I did `emerge nginx` with these flags enabled: `aio http http-cache http2 ipv6 pcre ssl NGINX_MODULES_HTTP=access addition auth_basic autoindex browser charset empty_gif fastcgi geo gzip limit_conn limit_req map memcached proxy referer rewrite scgi split_clients ssi upstream_ip_hash userid uwsgi`)

I added this to the default config

```
upstream django_upstream {
    server 127.0.0.1:17999;
}

upstream websocket_upstream {
    server 127.0.0.1:18000;
}

server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:80;
    server_name weby.com;

    access_log /tmp/web.com-access.log;
    error_log /tmp/web.com-error.log;

    location /static {
        alias /home/shaoran/projects/python/websockets/deployment/static;
    }

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django_upstream;
        include     /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
    }

    location /ws/ {
        proxy_pass http://websocket_upstream;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
```

I added `weby.com` to my `/etc/hosts` file and resolves to `127.0.0.1`. The last line in the `nginx` config I added after looking for my problem and found [this](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/1942) (see tylercb`s comment), so I added the`proxy_set_header Host $host;` line.

The `uWSGI` instances were started like this:

```
# exporting DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=websockets.deploy_settings


# the main django app
uwsgi --socket 127.0.0.1:17999 --wsgi-file websockets/wsgi.py --die-on-term --buffer-size=32768 --workers=5 --master --logto2 /tmp/wsgi_django.log

# the websocket app
uwsgi --socket 127.0.0.1:18000 --wsgi-file websockets/wsgi_websocket.py --die-on-term --gevent 1000 --http-websockets --workers=2 --master --logto2 /tmp/wsgi_websocket.log
```

Now when I go to http://weby.com the page doesn't show me the random strings. I opened the console (testing with google chrome) and I saw this error:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://weby.com/ws/foobar?subscribe-broadcast&publish-broadcast' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 502
```

In the console I executed again

```
ws = new WebSocket("ws://weby.com/ws/foobar?subscribe-broadcast&publish-broadcast")
```

to see what error message I would get in the log files. The `django` log files had nothing. The `nginx` error log file says

```
2016/11/21 01:16:17 [error] 12892#0: *1 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: weby.com, request: "GET /ws/foobar?subscribe-broadcast&publish-broadcast HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:18000/ws/foobar?subscribe-broadcast&publish-broadcast", host: "weby.com"
```

The `uWSGI` log file says

```
invalid request block size: 21573 (max 4096)...skip
```

So I googled that and found this: [uwsgi invalid request block size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15878176/uwsgi-invalid-request-block-size#26941287), so I added the `-b 32768` option to the `uwsgi` command for the `websocket` interface. When I executed

```
ws = new WebSocket("ws://weby.com/ws/foobar?subscribe-broadcast&publish-broadcast")
```

I didn't get any error message again. "Hooray" I thought, but no message arrived. After a couple of seconds I got the `Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 502` again :(

So I added the `--protocol=http` as suggested on the same thread and I got one message but nothing more. The `uWSGI` log says only

```
[pid: 13513|app: 0|req: 1/1] 127.0.0.1 () {42 vars in 786 bytes} [Mon Nov 21 00:42:08 2016] GET /ws/foobar?subscribe-broadcast&publish-broadcast => generated 58 bytes in 64418 msecs (HTTP/1.1 101) 4 headers in 178 bytes (3 switches on core 999)
```

and the `django` log says

```
Subscribed to channels: subscribe-broadcast, publish-broadcast
```

I reloaded the page and I finally got one message but after a couple of seconds the messages were not coming. I reloaded the page again with F5 and nothing, not even the first message like before.

So I tried closing the connection with `ws.close()` I got

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://weby.com/ws/foobar?subscribe-broadcast&publish-broadcast' failed: One or more reserved bits are on: reserved1 = 1, reserved2 = 0, reserved3 = 1
Websocket connection is broken!
```

and the `django` log says

```
WebSocketError: unable to receive websocket message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/shaoran/anaconda/websockets/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ws4redis/wsgi_server.py", line 120, in __call__
    recvmsg = RedisMessage(websocket.receive())
  File "/home/shaoran/anaconda/websockets/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ws4redis/uwsgi_runserver.py", line 31, in receive
    raise WebSocketError(e)
WebSocketError: unable to receive websocket message
```

I feel that I'm getting closer to the correct configuration, but here I don't know what goes wrong. The `nginx` config seems to be alright, so it must be something on how I execute `uwsgi`.

The thing is that is seems to work only randomly. I reloaded the page but this time I didn't do anything just kept waiting and see if something appears. I opened firefox and loaded the page, to see if this was a chrome issue. With firefox I had exactly the same, the only difference is that firefox doesn't show any error message when closing the connection, but the `django`log file shows the `WebSocketError` exception. I returned to the chrome page I reloaded a couple of minutes ago and to my surprise I found 5 new messages. I cannot reproduce this behaviour, it is always a different outcome.

What am I doing wrong?

---

**edit**

I think I found the problem. I modified my thread so:

```
# inside websockets/views.py

class WS(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.counter = 0

    def listen_and_replay_to_redis(self):

        logger = logging.getLogger("django")

        logger.debug(" >> websocket starting thread")

        try:

            redis_publisher = RedisPublisher(facility='foobar', broadcast=True)

            while True:
                data = str(uuid.uuid4())

                #self.counter += 1

                #data = "%s - %s" % (data, self.counter)

                redis_publisher.publish_message(RedisMessage(data))
                ttw = random.uniform(3, 10)
                ttw = 1
                logger.debug(" >> websocket thread %s: %s waiting %s seconds" % (datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S"), data, ttw))
                time.sleep(ttw)
        except Exception as e:
            logger.debug(" >> websocket thread error: %s" % e)

        logger.debug(" >> websocket thread dying")


obj = WS()
th = threading.Thread(target = obj.listen_and_replay_to_redis)
th.start()
```

When I start in debug mode I can see in the log file that the thread is running because it generates messages like this:

```
>> websocket thread 02:09:15: a2d460d4-a660-47ad-845d-1a60a6dddb14 waiting 1 seconds
>> websocket thread 02:09:16: 9313a0e9-8d07-42a7-8cd5-a2d1951d8ba0 waiting 1 seconds
>> websocket thread 02:09:17: fbbfc063-ecb2-4424-a017-1f943d3fdc2d waiting 1 seconds
```

When I start in production mode with `wsgi` I don't see anything. The first I make a request (`curl http://weby.com`) the log file shows

```
>> websocket starting thread
```

and nothing more. If I keep doing `curl http://weby.com` I sometimes see "websocket starting thread" message, sometimes the other lines. So that shows that either `RedisPublisher` and redis_publisher.publish_message block or the thread is killed. I've been reading different threads here about launching threads, I implemented the suggestions like starting the thread in the `urls.py` module (as it get loaded only once) or in the `uwsgi.py` file itself, nothing seems to work. How can I have a thread running in the background when deploying with uWSGI?

Comment: well the hole web sockets with django seems quite complex and fragile, i understand the benefit of having the website and web socket on the same project, however have you considered node.js, you ca do something with socket.io or socketcluster.io. pm2 it's a great way to deploy node Applications, and you can use ngix to have it all on the same domain. I have an app on django and node for the sockets.

Comment: @alex: thanks for the answer. I made an edit, because I think I found the problem, perhaps you could help me there. Yes I considered node.js but I haven't worked with it in the past and I didn't want to spend to much time learning how to use it, deploy it, etc. Don't get me wrong, it is not like I'm lazy and don't want to broaden my horizon, the problem is the client doesn't pay that much and I'm not allowed to spend to much hours on the project. So you think the best alternative would be having a separate `websocket` server outside of django?

Comment: Try using this documentation instead: https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html

Comment: mmm i get that, death lines, yea i really like node to handle the websockets, also there's tornado a python server (powers fb messenger), you can do web sockets very easily, however i think it would be hard to run on the same codebase as the django project, so yea a separate sever is my bad solution to your problem :/

Comment: thanks to all of you. I was searching in google for uWSGI and threads and I found this http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ThingsToKnow.html there is a section that says "By default the Python plugin does not initialize the GIL. This means your app-generated threads will not run. If you need threads, remember to enable them with enable-threads".

Comment: So I added the `--enable-threads` to the django uwsgi instance and start the thread in the `uwsgi.py` (it has to start before the `application = get_wsgi_application()` otherwise the thread runs but any HTTP request blocks. @alex: oh yes, I could use tornado or flask, but now it's running. Jesus, this was hard.

Comment: sorry for my multiple comments, but both comments together were just too long :(